# Error Query failed: Cannot unnest type: row

Tags: presto

I'm running a query with a

```
select bar_tbl.thing1
from foo
cross join unnest(bar) as t(bar_tbl)
```

And got the error `Error Query failed: Cannot unnest type: row`

Why?

The bar column looks like this `{thing1=abc, thing2=def}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to expand a row, which doesn't make sense. 
I should have just done

```
select bar.thing1
from foo
```

Comment: Any idea how to get ALL values in the row structure as columns (without specifying every single element)? For example, let's say I have a row structure with 20 elements, and I want to expand each into its own column (hopefully named as the key in the row). How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. did you managed to find a solution? @wardw123